# i don't receive any comment in webhook but i receive message in developers facebook panel

Tags: instagram-graph-api, facebook-webhooks, facebook-feed

My app is developing.
I select Instagram from the webhooks page on developers.facebook.com/app and I do not receive any notification in my webhook from the test button next to comments or live_comments, but I receive notifications for messages and message_reactions.
what is the problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLMJU.png

permissions:
instagram_manage_comments
pages_show_list
pages_manage_metadata
pages_manage_engagement
instagram_manage_insights
instagram_basic
pages_read_engagement
instagram_manage_messages
pages_messaging
read_insights
business_management
instagram_content_publish
instagram_manage_events
publish_video
email
page_events

subscribed_apps :
feed, mention,message_mention, messages, message_reactions, message_echoes, messaging_postbacks, messaging_feedback, group_feed, messaging_in_thread_lead_form_submit, leadgen, general_manager